# Open source fonts

Tags: css, open-source, fonts

Are there any good open source fonts to use in CSS.

Comment: Why? What is wrong with using ones that are widely supported instead of a custom font that people will have to download extra?

Comment: @webdestroya welcome to 2010.  @vinny see fontsquirrel.com, or the [Goggle font repository](http://code.google.com/webfonts).

Comment: Goddamnit people if you want to close a question, *post a comment explaining why*.  Newbies asking questions can't be expected to understand why some people don't like them simply because they've been closed.

Comment: @Pointy Fontsquirrel curates free, but not F/OS fonts. The League of Moveable Type is another one.

Comment: @Yi Jiang no, some of the Fontsquirrel fonts are open source - you have to check their licensing information.

Comment: Well, fair enough. @vinny Stack Overflow is for programming questions, and this is very obviously not under the scope of this site. The [ **faq** ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)explains very clearly what can be asked and what can't. Questions like this might be better suited for doctype.com instead.

Comment: Yes doctype is a good place to post the question, but honestly this is a question that Google would answer pretty competently in about 0.2 seconds.

Comment: @Pointy Amaaaazing. Never knew about this.

Comment: Ok sorry everyone. I thought whatever is related to webdesign can be asked. Will try to be careful the next time.

Comment: Vinny, web developers/designers have their own stack site here now: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at

- FontSquirrel - http://fontsquirrel.com
- The Goggle font directory - http://code.google.com/webfonts